# Embedded video is not playing on ipad or iphone

Tags: wordpress, video

Here is the site I'm working on. It's a wordpress theme. http://whatmyeyezsee.com/21-day-fix/ The embedded videos will play in the browser but it doesn't show up at all on my iphone, and my client says that browsing on her ipad she just can't play it. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by improper transcoding settings for iOS devices. Be sure you have set iOS rendition settings for your videos you intend to play on iPhones, iPod Touches, and iPads. When setting renditions for iOS devices, be sure to use the BASE codec container setting, not the MAIN or HIGH settings. Also this video is not playing on Safari too.

Please refer this documentation for Brightcove player.

https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/encoding-mobile-delivery

Comment: Thank you for your help. So she is embedding these videos from a company she works with. Would this be something we can fix on our end by changing the embedding code, or is it something the company itself needs to adjust?

Comment: That adjustment needs to be done while you upload the video to vimeo so I dont know who does that on your side but the person who upload the video to vimeo to crate the embed needs to do this